What is a 'dark state'?
I have obtained data regarding the absorption properties of a molecule, which reads as follows:
S1 560 nm, oscillator strength = 0.000059460  
S2 520 nm, oscillator strength = 0.247047563  
...

Given this information:

What are dark states in the context of molecular absorption and photophysics?
Can the S1 state be considered a "dark state"?
How should dark states be treated when analyzing molecular absorption data and interpreting their role in molecular processes (like intersystem crossing and phosphorescence)?

Thank you.

It would very much help your question if you define what your table represents, especially $f$, providing any units if appropriate. Please edit the question to provide this information.

Also logically question 2 should come first.

They are states that have very small probability of absorption/emission (due to tiny transition moment or Franck Condon factor) or those that are 'forbidden' by spin and or symmetry. The S1 state in some carotenes are forbidden and hence 'dark'


Dark states cannot be excited by linear absorption spectroscopy, and leave no signal in a normal UV/VIS absorption spectrum.

Strictly speaking no, since the transition dipole moment is not zero. Practically yes, as the peak may still be missing in an experiment with low sensitivity. And it could be covered by the much brighter S2 state in this case if that one has a broad peak. You most likely wont be able to excite only the S1 state in this case or extract it as well defined feature from background noise. I would call it an almost dark state.

This question is too broad. They only thing specific to a dark state is that they have zero (or very low) transition dipole moment coupling to the ground state. Which means that they can matter in all processes that are not fully described by this coupling element. Except for this, they act like any other state and are just as relevant.


Response to comment:
Internal conversion between states that are close in energy is usually faster than intersystem crossing, which is the case for the S2 and S1 in your calculation. From your limited description I would assume that the S2 is excited by light. This excitation is followed by fast internal conversion from the bright S2 to the dark S1 state. The excitation is "trapped" (see comments for clarification) there, due to the low transition dipole moment of the S1 state, which prevents fast fluorescence. This gives the S1 state time for intersystem crossing to a triplet state.
Ideally you would calculate all involved rates. I.e. the IC from the S2-S1, the ISC S2-T1, ISC S1-T1 and the fluorescence rates S2-S0, S1-S0. Or at least take a look at the coupling elements. I.e. the spin-orbit couplings the transition dipole moments, and the nonadiabatic coupling.

Additional explanation: I am interested in the intersystem crossing. The molecule obeys Kasha's rule. However, given that S1 is small, shouldn't I also consider S2 → Tn in addition to just S1->Tn?

@farmaceut See updated answer.

Thanks :) So in case of low oscillator strength (let's stick with labeling them as dark ones), considering up to the first bright excitation, and then ICs and ISCs is the correct way to examine the process.

I think that your statement ' The excitation is trapped there...' is confusing. Perhaps what you mean is that the fluorescence rate constant is v. small but that intersystem crossing rate constant is large so more triplets are formed vs fluorescence photons i.e. the total rate constant out of S1 is $k_f+k_{isc}$ hence if $k_{isc}\gg k_f$ there is almost no fluorescence and no 'trapping' or 'giving time' for intersystem crossing.

@porphyrin That is exactly what I meant, and why I put trapped into quotation marks. I was to lazy to type it out.

@HansWurst, I’m really just wondering in what cases I should consider higher states than S₁, and if it’s even reasonable given that k_IC > k_ISC >> k_f
